# How to unload/un-require gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capybara, calabash

I'm working on mobile ⇔ web tests, combining Calabash and Capybara gems. The gems call methods that have the same name (like `page`), and I find it hard to make my code execute methods of desired files.

Can I un-require a gem? Please let me know if this is possible and whether it is a good idea.

Comment: Do they have the same method names in the same class?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I un-require a gem?

No.

`require` simply runs the file. Period. "Unrequiring" would then basically mean running the file in reverse, undoing everything the code did. But that is impossible. Imagine a very simple gem which only contains this single line:

```
print "\a"
```

This will cause the computer to beep once. "Unrequiring" would then mean that everybody who is in the vicinity of the computer would forget that they heard the beep. That's just ridiculous.

There are programming languages, libraries, and calculi, which are explicitly designed such that they can – under very limited, heavily restricted circumstances – be "run in reverse", but Ruby is not such a language.

Comment: simple but very effective answer!